# Scroll cell is displayed at top of screen

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a shared Google Sheet, users enter their hours against each job, as a forecasting tool. The jobs are in 3 groups, so I want to have a script so users can easily scroll to their relevant section.

I have written a script, and it executes correctly. It finds the heading string in column A, returns the row number, and then activates the cell containing the heading.

```
// global variables
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var err_msg = "Sorry, can't find link to "
var lastcell = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 1); //row, column, numRows, numColumns


// search in column A:A for the headings, returns row number
function findInColumn(data) {

  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange('A1:A' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();    // column + ":" + column like A:A

  //var values = column.getValues(); 
  var row = 0;

  while ( values[row] && values[row][0] !== data ) {
    row++;
  }

  if (values[row][0] === data) 
    return row+1;
  else 
    return -1;

}


function jumpTo_LargeScaleHybrid() {

  var data = "LARGE SCALE / HYBRID";
  var rownum = findInColumn(data);

  var range = sheet.getRange(rownum, 1, 1, 1); //row, column, numRows, numColumns

  if (rownum && -1) {
    sheet.setActiveRange(range);
  }
  else {
    Browser.msgBox("Sorry, can't find link to 'LARGE SCALE / HYBRID'. Someone must have changed the target name.");
  }
}
```

However, the selected cell is at the bottom of the screen whereas I'd like it at the top.

If the starting position is at the bottom of the list of jobs, then it works. But not if the starting position is at the top, where most users begin.

Comment: Do you mind a workaround where you hide the rows from above that you don't need? Because apparently setActiveRange() will not allow to put the scroll as you want and probably hiding them could help.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work. I really just need a way to "jump" to the right place and have it display nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a workaround for my issue, using the Flush command.

I was able to select/activate the last cell in the column, execute the .flush command, and then (effectively) scroll up to the cell I want

```
var lastcell = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 1)
sheet.setActiveRange(lastcell);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
sheet.setActiveRange(range);
```